How to unit test call to quit?
I have a function that uses quit on some very particular scenario and I would like to create a unit test for it, however anything that I wrap inside testthat functions or try or tryCatch would anyway exit R immediately.
Is there a way to create a unit test for such case?
Here is a quick reproducible example of the function
mock_quit <- function(n) {
  if (n > 1) {
    cat("TERMINATING ERROR")
    quit(save = "no", status = 1, T)
  }
}

It would be enough to test that "TERMINATING ERROR" is printed or that quit takes effect. Whichever it is, it is important that R would not end the session in order to continue with other tests.

Look at callr::r.
mock_quit <- function(n) {
  err <- TRUE
  try(
    {
      callr::r(\(x) if (x > 1) quit(save = "no", status = 1, TRUE), args = list(n))
      err <- FALSE
    }
    , silent = TRUE
  )
  err
}

mock_quit(2)
#> [1] TRUE
mock_quit(0)
#> [1] FALSE

